# Configure Home Network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking

Hey guys I just got to the point where I can't take it anymore and need to fix my home network.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/16lMZ.png]

My questions Are:

1. What is the best setup for the routers?
2. My PS4 can connect to the network through the router but don't have internet access. When it is connected to the modem it works fine. I want to connect it to the network so that it can read the DLNA server.
3. When pretty much in the middle of the distance between the Cisco and the AirPort, the Wi-Fi gets really slow. Wi-Fi signal conflict maybe?

@Edit:

**Q: How many square feet (or square meters) of floor space in your home?**

A: I live in an apartment which has two floors is kind of big, don't know exactly the measure.

**Q: What's the make/model of the modem?**

A: It is from the internet provider GVT (I live in Brazil BTW) and it is indeed an awful modem. Can't do anything about it. It is a modem with a custom software.

Pace
model: V5471

**Q: What are the exact model numbers of the AirPort Extreme and the Time Capsule?**

A: AirPort Extreme 802.11ac (6th Generation), version: 7.7.3
About the Time Capsule, sorry if it wasn't clear, it is not the hardware Time Capsule, it is just a hard drive connected to the AirPort which is used for Time Machine backups from my MacBook Pro.

**Q: What speed of Internet service are you paying for?**

A: 25Mb (Yeah..Brazil...)

**Q: Are all of those arrows wired Ethernet links, or are some wireless (which ones)?**

A: All of the arrows are wired cables.

**Q:    Is outgoing arrow mean a WAN and incoming a LAN?**

A: No, i got that wrong, the arrows should be all the same. From the modem to the Cisco it is WAN, from 1 Cisco LAN it goes to the AirPort WAN, from other 1 Cisco LAN it goes to TP LINK WAN.

**Q: Is there a reason to make so many sub-networks?**

A: I Don't know if I understood but, they have all the same SSID, I want them to divide the Traffic in the network so that It won't be concentrated in one router.

**Q: Listing of IP configuration (with masks, gateways and routings) of all you devices will help a little.**

A:  Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
    Gateway: 192.168.25.1
    Routing: Want to know how to do that actually.
Only device that has a static ip address is the Raspberry Pi (192.168.1.135) as i did some port forwarding on the Cisco to access it  remotely with no-ip.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a crazy network that could use some optimization. How many square feet (or square meters) of floor space in your home? What's the make/model of the modem? What are the exact model numbers of the AirPort Extreme and the Time Capsule? What speed of Internet service are you paying for? Are all of those arrows wired Ethernet links, or are some wireless (which ones)?

Comment: Updated the thread with the info.

Comment: Is your AirPort Extreme a tower, or a flat square? If it's a tower, then it's the 802.11ac AirPort Extreme from 2013, not 802.11n. It makes sense that it would be the 802.11ac tower if it's running 7.7.3, because the 802.11n flat squares never went beyond 7.6.x.

Comment: Oh, I got it wrong. It is the Tower

Comment: Is outgoing arrow mean a WAN and incoming a LAN?  Is there a reason to make so many sub-networks? Listing of IP configuration (with masks, gateways and routings) of all you devices will help a little...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, well, I don't speak or read Portuguese, but it appears that your modem is actually a full-featured home gateway with integrated VDSL modem, simultaneous dual-band 802.11ac Wi-Fi AP, and VoIP telephone adapters all built in.

So you have 4 separate "wireless routers" on your network, all supporting different flavors of 802.11. The worst of which is the Cisco E900, which is only 2x2 802.11n, and only one band at a time (so you probably have it configured for 2.4GHz).

Here are some things I recommend you do:

1. **Make it one big bridged network behind a single NAT gateway/DHCP server.**

   Disable the NAT gateway and DHCP Server services on all the routers except the GVT Pace V5471 gateway. You want only that Pace device at the head of your network being the NAT gateway and DHCP server for the whole network. You want the rest of your "wireless routers" to just be plain 802.11 Access Points, transparently bridging traffic between wireless clients and the wired network.

   On the AirPort Extreme, when you switch it from NAT to Bridge mode, it will automatically make the WAN port part of the LAN side switch. Some other brands of wireless routers aren't that smart, and don't give you a way to use the WAN port except in NAT mode. If that applies to your E900 or TP-Link, then stop using that box's WAN port, and plug its LAN port into the wired Ethernet LAN. Disable NAT and DHCP Server services if you can. If you can't disable DHCP service, try setting the DHCP server's address lease pool to a zero-length range.

   Leaving NAT enabled on your downstream routers is probably what's blocking your PS4 from getting to your DLNA server.
2. **Figure out your channel plan**

   With this many APs in one apartment, they're bound to interfere with each other if any of them are sharing the same channels.

   For their 2.4GHz radios, consider putting them on channels 1, 5, 9, and 13 (a little frequency overlap with this channel plan, but probably not enough to hurt) or channels 1, 6, 11, and 1 (select the two that are farthest apart to be the ones that are both on channel 1). If they let you select channel widths of 20MHz-only vs 20/40MHz mode, I'd recommend you put them all on 20MHz-only mode, to they interfere less with each other, and with Bluetooth and other users of the 2.4GHz band. This move limits their 2.4GHz Wi-Fi speed, but solving the interference hassles may be worth the trade-off.

   For their 5GHz radios, put one on channel 36, one on channel 149, and one on channel 52, 100, or 132. Consider using channel 149 on the AirPort Extreme. I know it has a high-power radio, and in many radio-regulator jurisdictions, channels 149-161 can use more power than other parts of the 5GHz band. All your devices that can do 5GHz can do AC, so make sure they're all set to use 80MHz-wide channels (the AirPort Extreme does this by default and probably doesn't let you limit it to 40 or 20MHz).
3. **Get a Gigabit Ethernet switch instead of the 100Mbit Cisco E900.**

   Your E900 is a bottleneck on your wired network because it only does 100Mbit Ethernet, not Gigabit Ethernet like the Pace and the AirPort (and probably the TP-Link) do.
4. **Unify your Wi-Fi to 1300Mbps 802.11ac**

   Consider upgrading the Cisco and TP-Link boxes to something that does simultaneous dual-band, 3-stream 802.11ac just like your GVT/Pace gateway and your 2013 AirPort Extreme do. I like the AirPort Extreme because of how reliable it is and the high-power transmitters it uses, but if you want to save money, the TP-Link Archer C7 might be a fine choice.

   Right now, if you wander around your apartment, if you get to where you're only in range of the Cisco E900, you'll suddenly only have 300Mbps connectivity (if that), whereas if you're near the AirPort Extreme, you could have 1300Mbps connectivity (if you wireless card also supports 3-stream 802.11ac).

Comment: Hey, so the problem is: Even if the Pace sound like a good modem/router, if you search a little bit in Brazilian forums you would discover that its Wi-Fi signal is awful. For the record, when it was installed in my house, even though I should have 25Mb,the Wi-Fi was going up and down from 1Mb to 7Mb as I was in front of the Pace.     So, I deactivated the Wi-Fi signal from it.

Comment: @Felipe Yes, if it has bad Wi-Fi support, it's better to turn it off than leave it on. But if that makes the Cisco E900 the only device providing Wi-Fi coverage for that part of the apartment, then you have yet another reason to buy an other AirPort Extreme or other modern 3-stream-or-better 802.11ac AP to cover that area. The TP-Link C20i isn't great either, as it only does single-stream 802.11ac (433Mbps instead of 1300Mbps).

Comment: Well, right now buying something like that is off-limits for me. You see, while in USA you can buy an AirPort Extreme for $190 on bestbuy, here in Brazil the price is R$2099 equivalent to $566.62